# Redirect to the front page with a different language

Tags: 8, redirection

i have a question about redirecting to a page with a different language. I found this old post for drupal 7 but I doesn't really help me - https://www.drupal.org/node/1280468

Now we are in Drupal 8 and the redirect works like this:

```
return new RedirectResponse(\Drupal::url('<front>'))
```

But how can I set the language for the redirect? In my code I have the languagecode like NZ for New Zealand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try this code

```
 <?php

 use Drupal\Core\Url;
 use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

 $language = Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage('vi');
 $url = Url::fromRoute('<front>', [], ['language' => $language]);
 $response = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
 $response->send();
```

Comment: It works but you can't pass 'nz', because it's not a language-code. It would be en-au for example

Answer (score -1):

Within your controller method:

```
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute('<front>')->toString();
return new RedirectResponse($url);
```

Comment: doesn't work, return current language